# Cypress typing error - jumbling input in textarea

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

My Cypress test gets a `textarea`, clears it, and types `Comments mod test`.

```
cy.get('textarea.comment').then(ta => {
cy.wrap(ta).clear().type(`Comments mod test`)
```

But the intermittent result is `omments mod testC` causing the test to fail an equality assertion. It appears the cursor is jumping back to the beginning of the line after typing the initial `C`.  Is this what's happening, if so how to prevent it, if not, what gives?

[image: jumbled text]

Comment: It may be a bug in your code that does this - is there an on change handler on the input field?

Comment: @Mikkel excellent question.  there is an `input` handler but all it does is increment an integer--it doesn't change focus or do anything else with the dom.  I'll add a `debounce` and see if that helps.

Comment: The issue was used of `clear()`. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the use of `clear()`

`clear()` is an alias for `type('{selectall}{backspace}')`

Through several permutations of the test code, I landed on two which consistently failed and worked, exclusively.

The use of `clear()` in a slight variation on that in the question consistently caused the collapse of the `div` containing the `textarea`, nested in an accordion view, causing the `textarea` to become non-visible. Cypress is unable to `type()` execute tasks on non-visible elements.

Omission of `{backspace}` consistently works.

The working test code:

```
cy.get('textarea.comment').type('{selectall}Comments mod test').then(() => {...
```

Comment: Which essentially means "issue might be on the website itself", because .clear() as such working fine a usual text input in my test result above :).

Comment: @PravyNandas Your answer is tantamount to "the problem with your test is your application."  The problem, as stated in the question, was in the _test_, which was not behaving as intended, and not in the application. This was not a case where a test was simply failing an assertion. It was a case where a test was not executing completely. The problem was specifically that `clear` fails under certain circumstances. The solution is to implement an alternative to `clear` in the test code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue might be on the website itself, doing some kind of cursor movement. I was able to get expected result from your code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with delay=0, it will help this issue never happen again ^^

```
cy.get('[data-testid="xxx"]').find('textarea').type('Hello world', { delay: 0 });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this Cypress config option:

```
parseSpecialCharSequences: false
```

With this, you don't need any of the additional `{sequence}` parameters in your `.type` statement.

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type